# Remove snow and ice on car windshield without ice scrapper

Tags: winter, car

Sometimes I am caught off guard when winter starts early and I find myself at some place away from home, my car covered with snow and I don't have an ice scraper on me. I typically just turn on the car, brush off as much snow as I can with my arm, and wait for the car to heat up enough to melt the ice. This however is time consuming and costly (wastes gas).

What's a good way to clear the ice if I don't have an ice scrapper?

Comment: Similar: [How to keep the windshield from freezing over?](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/104/2272)

Comment: Not a duplicate, the other question is answered by using water and a scrapper which you wouldn't have access to in this situation.

Comment: However it is duplicated here: http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/495/what-can-i-use-for-an-improvised-ice-scraper?lq=1